# Moving already read Avro Files from One Directory to Another Using Azure DataFactory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-eventhub

I have an Eventhub Capture which emits **Avro Files** Every 15 minutes. I can successfully read these files with an Azure Data Factory Data Flow however how can I move **these files** once I have finished reading them using an Azure DataFactory Pipeline?

There will be new files coming in and I don't want to move the new files only the already processed files to an archive folder.

I tried to do a GetMetadata Activity and then Delete but it doesn't seem to be able to ready Avro Files in a directory. Could be I'm missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data flow can handle this organically:

[image]